# Targeting a particular div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this in my HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="image">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png" alt="Bart"/>
            <div class="caption">Bart Simpson</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Lisa_Simpson.png" alt="Lisa"/>
            <div class="caption">Lisa Simpson</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png" alt="Homer"/>
            <div class="caption">Homer Simpson</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my Jquery, I add a class with some text into the class image. However, using:

```
$(".image").append(data[index]);
```

where data is an array containing the new class code, the code goes into all instances of the class image. Now, what I want to do is: based on the index, I want to the add the new code into a particular image class. So for index 0, I want to add the code to the class with Bart, for index 1, to the class with Lisa and so on...

I can't use if statements since the number of images in the HTML might change but not the js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to select elements based on their index.

```
$('.image').eq(index).append(data[index]);
```

I'm guessing you want something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `.append()`:

```
$(".image").append(function(index) {
    return data[index];
});
```

Such functions are passed the element index as the first parameter. (The current HTML contents are passed as a string as the second argument, but my example doesn't need that.)

Answer (score 0):

The each function will run the function for every element that matches the selection, in this case `.image`.  Each time the each() function is run, the index is passed to the var `index`.  So this:

```
$(".image").each(function (index, element) {
  $(element).append(data[index]);
});
```

Will append the correct data to the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for a div with class 'image' at a particular index you can do :

```
$('.image')[index].append(data[index])
```

or

```
$('.image').eq(index).append(data[index]);
```

If you want to do it for all divs with image classes you have to use a loop

in that case

```
$('.image').each(function(index,current)){
    $(current).append(data[index]);
}
```